# istio version on gke and upgrading it

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio, envoyproxy

I wanted to try deploying WASM extension on gke using this demo application
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo

Realized that GKE doesn't support istio 1.5.x yet https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/versions

So I just tried
`$> istioctl upgrade --force`
and got 'installation complete' message as in here
https://gist.github.com/taegyunkim/dc00a34934968bd6adf13fb2b5ec1ff9
then restarted the pods as suggested

To verify update, I ran `$> istioctl version` and got this:

```
client version: 1.5.2
citadel version: 1.4.6-gke.0
galley version: 1.4.6-gke.0
ingressgateway version: 1.4.6-gke.0
pilot version: 1.4.6-gke.0
policy version: 1.4.6-gke.0
sidecar-injector version: 1.4.6-gke.0
telemetry version: 1.4.6-gke.0
pilot version: 1.5.2
data plane version: 1.4.6-gke.0 (18 proxies)
```

It doesn't look like it's updated. Is there a way to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove old istio version
2. istioctl manifest apply [ this will install default profile ]
3. if Demo profile needed then
   istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no possibility to install `Istio` version `1.5.X` with `GCP Cloud Console` as shown below:

[image: Enable Istio]

The newest version is `1.4.6-gke.0` as described here: [Cloud.google.com: Istio: Versions](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/versions)

There is a Feature Request to support `Istio 1.5.X` on [Issuetracker.google.com: Istio 1.5 on GKE](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154150610)

---

The best way to install `Istio 1.5.X` on a `GKE` cluster would be:

- Determine if existing cluster have applications that cannot be deleted:

  - If **Yes** then follow official documentation: [Cloud.google.com: Istio: Uninstalling](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/uninstalling)
  - If **No** create a new cluster **without** enabling `Istio` in `GCP Dashboard`.
- Get credentials to `GKE` cluster with `gcloud`.
- Follow documentation on `Istio` site to install `istioctl`: [Istio.io: Install Istioctl](https://istio.io/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/istioctl/#install-hahahugoshortcode-s2-hbhb).
- Run command: `istioctl manifest apply`.

After this steps, command: `$ istioctl version` should output:

```sh
client version: 1.5.4
control plane version: 1.5.4
data plane version: 1.5.4 (2 proxies)
```

Please let me know if you have any question in that.

Comment: I guess Istio on GKE is not Google's priority, as they want to promote Anthos Service mesh, which receives regular updates and already supports Istio 1.6.
https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/release-notes